# How to add value to the resulting height?

Tags: jquery

**Code:**

```
alert($("#Test").css("height")); //300px;
```

How to add value to the resulting height?

P.S.: me need add 100px with $("#Test").css("height").

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Test').css( "height", "+=100" );
```

will add 100 to the existing height

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

*make element 100px in height*

```
$("#Test").css({"height":100});
```

or this?

*increment element height by 100px*

```
$("#Test").css({"height":"+=100"});
```

p.s. start using `console.dir()` instead of `alert()`

p.p.s. documentation is your friend, [look here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's padding-left was 10px, .css( "padding-left", "+=15" ) would result in a total padding-left of 25px.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the anonymous function of `css()` method:

```
$("#Test").css("height", function (i, h) {
    return h + 100;
});
```